# Load text from txt file

Tags: jquery, text, load

I need to be able to update a date on a site via a txt file (or xml or whatever is easiest).
This is what the html looks like right now, and I need the line "THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC" to be loaded from an external file which I easily can update.

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>LOREM IPSUM:<br />
          THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC
          <div class="separator"></div>
          LOREM IPSUM<br />
          LOREM IPSUM<br />
          LOREM IPSUM</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to wrap "THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC" with a span-element to make it easier to select?

Comment: You could use `load()` http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: What technology renders your HTML? There are about 47 different approaches to this, no one can tell which one is appropriate for you without more information.

Comment: @Christofer Eliasson: yes absolutely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the text:

```
<span id="dynamicdate">THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC</span>
```

Then you can use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$(function(){
   $.get("your-url-to-file.txt", function(data) {
      $("#dynamicdate").html(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: This seems to work in dreamweavers live view, but as soon as I test it in a browser, the "THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC" text hasn't changed?

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen Do you get any JS-errors in the browser?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Craig%20Kristensen/Desktop/myurl.txt. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @CraigJonathanKristensen Yes, if you just run it locally you will probably get a problem with the same-origin policy, since browser will not see that the page and the file origin from within the same domain, and will therefore block the request for security reasons - I think!

Answer (score 0):

Add a Span:

```
<span id="unique-id-here">THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC</span>
```

Then use jQuery to get the data from the text file:

```
$.get('myurl.txt',function(data){
    $('#unique-id-here').html(data);
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't seem to work. I have a txt file (myurl.txt) next to my html file.

Comment: This seems to work in dreamweavers live view, but as soon as I test it in a browser, the "THIS SHOULD BE DYNAMIC" text hasn't changed?